# Calling a Variable from another Class

Tags: c#, class, variables, static

How can I access a variable in one public class from another public class in C#?

I have:

```
public class Variables
{
   static string name = "";
}
```

I need to call it from:

```
public class Main
{
}
```

I am working in a Console App.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That would just be:

```
 Console.WriteLine(Variables.name);
```

and it needs to be public also:

```
public class Variables
{
   public static string name = "";
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, and I get:
Variables.name is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: are you sure you added the public modifier.

Comment: When I responded, for some reason I didn't see the public modifier you added. Yes, it worked. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: I get an object reference is required for non-static field.

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest to use a variable instead of a public field:

```
public class Variables
{
   private static string name = "";

   public static string Name
   { 
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }

   }
}
```

From another class, you call your variable like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
         string var = Variables.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it would be better for him to not have variables within a static class.

Comment: why do you say that...why not?

Comment: It may just be me, but I think it is good practice to make static classes completely stateless.

Comment: @Chaos: Well, I could agree with you. But in this case, the variable name seems to be a constant and it seems to me more elegant to use a static variable.

Comment: why not use (public const String name = "MyName";) ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify an access modifier for your variable. In this case you want it public.

```
public class Variables
{
    public static string name = "";
}
```

After this you can use the variable like this.

```
Variables.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    Variable va = new Variable();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        va.name = "Stackoverflow";
    }
}
```