# How do I call an variable from another class in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I come from Java and I'm picking up C# scripting, I've had this issue for around two days now looking for solutions, I've tried setting the class to an instance and everything. This is for a miniature game project that I am working on with some friends.

Either way, I have StatHandler.cs which handles all of our statpoints... then I have HealthManager.cs which is supposed to handle all of the Health Related stuff.

The problem is, I can't for the life of me figure out how to call the variables such as

```
public int stamina, strength, agility, dexterity, wisdom;
```

from StatHandler.cs

I know that in Java it would be as easy as

```
maxHealth = StatHandler.stamina * 10;
```

Although, you cannot do that with C#, when creating an instance the code looks like this

```
maxHealth = StatHandler.instance.stamina * 10;
```

which provides me with the error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I've also tried inherriting, by doing this

```
public class HealthHandler : StatHandler {
```

**but it sets all the values to 0 in the HealthHandler class, it doesn't read anything.**

---

I really just need to figure out how to pull the variable from the other C# files, because this is slowing me way down.

Comment: [here is how to do it for a long journey](http://books.google.com.sg/books/about/Head_First_C.html?id=Rnea7qV_qQAC&redir_esc=y) and here is how you [do it for now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392017/calling-a-variable-from-another-class-c) ;)

Comment: seems like you're trying to access stamina as though it was a static field.. either make it static in StatHandler or create a new instance of StatHandler and get stamina from it.

Comment: ..."picking up C# scripting"..."call variables"..."pull variables from C# files"... this terminology is very exotic. Other than that, it is the same as in Java: you need an object instance to access non-static fields of a class.

Comment: StatHandler.instance is not creating an instance. Are you sure you are from Java? Maybe from JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually same as in Java. For non-static variables you need a class instance:

```
StatHandler sh = new StatHandler();
maxHealth = sh.stamina * 10;
```

or you can declare variables as static in the class like

```
public static string stamina = 10;
```

and then access it

```
maxHealth = StatHandler.stamina * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can't use a value type variable without initialize it.

Looks like `StatHandler.instance`  is `static` method. You can't use your `int` variables without any assigned. Assign some values to them.

For example

```
public int stamina = 1, strength = 2, agility = 3, dexterity = 4, wisdom = 5;
```

Comment: They are assigned later on in my code, using the Library i initiate all my variables on the scripts Start() function, which i apply the value of 10 to all of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

You need to initialize properly. Seems like `StatHandler.instance` is static and not initialized.

You can initialize it in `static` constructor

```
class StatHandler
{

  static StatHandler()
  {
      instance = new Instance(); // Replace Instance with type of instance
  }
}
```

Comment: but, considering this is going to be multiplayer when we finish with it, wouldn't using static variables on a script attatched to the player backfire, and cause every player to have the same stats?

Comment: It would, it should be instance member. But that is design issue, you will encounter many such issues. You can write down all the requirements, create object model, and then if you have further issue, you should ask at programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to go here.

**Full Static Class**

```
public static class StatHandler
{
    public static Int32 Stamina = 10;
    public static Int32 Strength = 5;
}
```

And then:

```
maxHealth = StatHandler.Stamina * 10; // get the value and use it
StatHandler.Stamina = 19; // change the value
```

**Singleton Instance**

```
public class StatHandler
{
    public static StatHandler Instance;

    public Int32 Stamina = 10;
    public Int32 Strength = 5;

    // this is called only the first time you invoke the class
    static StatHandler()
    {
        m_Instance = new Instance(); // Replace Instance with type of instance
    }
}
```

And then:

```
maxHealth = StatHandler.Instance.Stamina * 10; // get the value and use it
StatHandler.Instance.Stamina = 19; // change the value

// replace the current instance:
StatHandler.Instance = new StatHandler();
StatHandler.Instance.Stamina = 19; // change the value
```

I think the first one is always the best choice, same result, less complexity.