# How to access a variable from a class from another in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new in C# so I know it's a rookie question. I've been searching on this site similar questions but didn't find any.

I have two forms: `MainForm` and `EditForm` . `MainForm` has a class instance like in this code:

```
       public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ...
        RSSSourcesLibrary NewsSourcesCollection = new RSSSourcesLibrary();
        ...
    }
```

(the `RSSSourcesLibrary` class is defined somewhere else, in a third file)

How can I access `NewsSourcesCollection` from `EditForm`?

Comment: Do you create EditForm from MainForm ?

Comment: @Magnus yes. An instance of EditForm is created in a MainForm event handler. I want to be able to acces NewsSourcesCollection from an event handler in EditForm

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392017/calling-a-variable-from-another-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a Variable from another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392017/calling-a-variable-from-another-class)

Comment: When you create the EditForm send NewsSourcesCollection the the ctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating the EditForm from the MainForm, you need to mark it as owner (enabling you to access the owner property from EditForm), while creating it in MainForm

Creating EditForm in MainForm

```
EditForm editForm = new EditForm();
editForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Accessing from Edit Form

```
var value = ((MainForm)this.Owner).NewsSourcesCollection;
```

Where NewsSourcesCollection is declared as Public Property in MainForm