# I can't access a variable in another of my classes even if I make the variable a static method or create a new instance of the class in question?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, public, game-development

I'm currently developing a game in Unity and I ran into a small problem. I'm trying to access a variable that is located in another class because I need it in order to be able to spawn a gameobject ("clock") at random during a specified amount of time while an update method is running. However for some reason even if I change the variable to a static variable or create a new instance of the class in which the variable I'm trying to access is located. I keep on getting an error message stating:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object InteractControl.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Scene 2
>   Scripts/InteractControl.cs:87)

This is part of the class that I'm trying to access showing how the variable in question ("public Transform[] spawnPoints") is declared:

```cs
    public class BallSpawnerControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform[] spawnPoints = new Transform[] { };
        int randomSpawnPoint, Interact;
        int index = 1;
        public static bool spawnAllowed;
        public static int TimerOn = 1;
        ObjectPooler objectPooler;
        public static int LevelTrans = 1;
        public static bool HeartSpawn = false;
        private int Hearts = 1;

        // Use this for initialization
        public void Start()
        {
            objectPooler = ObjectPooler.Instance;
            spawnAllowed = true;
            InvokeRepeating("SpawnAInteract", 0f, 1f);
        }
```

This is part of the class that is trying to access the variable showing how the variable in question ("public Transform[] spawnPoints") is being accessed:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class InteractControl : MonoBehaviour, IPooledObject
    {
        private Rigidbody2D rb;
        GameObject target;
        Vector3 directionToTarget;
        public static int LevelStart = 0;
        Renderer m_Renderer;
        public static float moveSpeed = 5f;
        public static bool isSlowMotion = true;
        public static float timeLeft = 5f;
        ObjectPooler objectPooler = ObjectPooler.Instance;
        int randomSpawnPosition;
        float randomSpawnTime;
        int Spawn = 1;
        BallSpawnerControl Bc = new BallSpawnerControl();

     void Update()
        {
            if (target != null)
            {
                if (ScoreScript.scoreValue > 10) 
                {
                    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;

                    if (timeLeft > 0)
                    {
                        directionToTarget = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
                        rb.velocity = new Vector2(directionToTarget.x * moveSpeed,
                                                    directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);

                        if (Spawn == 1)
                        {
                            randomSpawnTime = Random.Range(1, 5);
                            randomSpawnPosition = Random.Range(0, Bc.spawnPoints.Length);
                            Spawn++;
                        }

                        if (timeLeft > randomSpawnTime && Spawn <= 2)
                        {
                            objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Clock", Bc.spawnPoints[randomSpawnPosition].position, Quaternion.identity);
                        }

                    }

                    if (timeLeft < 0)
                    {
                        GameObject[] gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ColouredBall Highress");

                        foreach (GameObject go in gos)
                        {
                            go.SetActive(false);
                        }

                        BallSpawnerControl.HeartSpawn = true;
                    }
                }    
            }            
        }
    }
```

What normally should happen is that the clock will spawn randomly at position "Bc.spawnPoints[randomSpawnPosition].position" during the 5 first seconds that ScoreScript.scoreValue > 10 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a Variable from another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392017/calling-a-variable-from-another-class)

Comment: You can access it, it just `null`. You never initialize it `spawnPoints = new Transform[size];`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: In which line is the exception thrown .. the code you showed here has only 63 lines ...? Did you actually fill the `spawnPoints` array with elements? Btw `new Transform[] { };` is unnecessary here since this is a `MonoBehaviour` and your array public Unity will serialize it and initialize it by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a variable from another script in another gameobject through GetComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551575/how-to-access-a-variable-from-another-script-in-another-gameobject-through-getco)

Comment: Is it possible that the `spawnPoints` referenced get destroyed on runtime or are prefabs?

Comment: I found another way to solve the problem. I just created a public static bool in BallSpawnerControl  the class I normally instantiate from and set it to true when I need to instantiate the object. It's not as accurate as instantiating from InteractControl since it is dependent on an invoke repeating but it works

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line of code.

```
BallSpawnerControl Bc = new BallSpawnerControl();
```

You create a new ballspawnercontrol in your class. However, since BallSpawnerControll is a MonoBehaviour, it will not instantiate correctly.

you should either attach the ballspawner control to a gameobject within Unity and then drag it into a field on your `InteractControl`.
Or you can create it via script by using the `AddComponent` method.

However, if you create it via script then you would also have to manually declare the spawnPoints from script. I suspect that you want to assign the values from within the inspector.

I suggest making your `Bc` variable either serializable or public.

```
public BallSpawnerControl Bc;
```

OR

```
[SerializeField]
private BallSpawnerControl Bc;
```

Now you can assign the correct control from the scene into your script.

Comment: I changed the code to reflect the comments made by @Markus , I also changed the if statement that encapsulates objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Clock", Bc.spawnPoints.... since it didnt work when I just did == however now I get the error message: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds for the line: objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Clock", Bc.spawnPoints[randomSpawnPosition].position, Quaternion.identity); do you possibly know why?

Comment: I found another way to solve the problem. I just created a public static bool in BallSpawnerControl  the class I normally instantiate from and set it to true when I need to instantiate the object. It's not as accurate as instantiating from InteractControl since it is dependent on an invoke repeating but it works