# Accessing variable from one class from another

Tags: c#, variables, scope, chatbot, profanity

I want to use a variable out of file "a" in file "b". I searched online a bit but it still doesn't work.

So I got the file `bot.cs` and the file `profanityFilter.cs`.

In the `profanityFilter.cs` I want to use the `incomingMessage` from `bot.cs`.

**bot.cs:**

```
class Bot
{
        public static void Client_OnMessageReceived(object sender, OnMessageReceivedArgs e)
        {
            var incomingMessage = e.ChatMessage.Message;

            //Profanity filter testing received message (need to get incoming message over to profanityFilter.cs)

            profanityFilter.Filter();

            Console.WriteLine($"[{TwitchInformation.BotName}]: [{e.ChatMessage.DisplayName}]: 
            {e.ChatMessage.Message}");
        }
}
```

**profanityFilter.cs:**

```
class profanityFilter
{
        public static async void Filter()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            Bot message = new Bot();
            var incomingMessagesFromUser = message.Client_OnMessageReceived.IncomingMessages;

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://neutrinoapi-bad-word-filter.p.rapidapi.com/bad-word-filter"),
                Headers =
                {
                    { "x-rapidapi-key", "xxx" },
                    { "x-rapidapi-host", "neutrinoapi-bad-word-filter.p.rapidapi.com" },
                },
                Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "censor-character", "*" },
                    { "content", incomingMessagesFromUser },
                }),
            };

            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(body);
            }
        }
}
```

But I get an error shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a Variable from another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392017/calling-a-variable-from-another-class)

Comment: Not realy, `Console.WriteLine(Client_OnMessageReceived.IncommingMessages);`  is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply have `profanityFilter.Filter` accept an argument, the message from the bot i.e.

`public static async void Filter(string message)`

```
    public static async void Filter(string message)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://neutrinoapi-bad-word-filter.p.rapidapi.com/bad-word-filter"),
            Headers =
            {
                { "x-rapidapi-key", "xxx" },
                { "x-rapidapi-host", "neutrinoapi-bad-word-filter.p.rapidapi.com" },
            },
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {[enter image description here][1]
                { "censor-character", "*" },
                { "content", message },
            }),
        };
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(body);
        }
    }
```

PS: Usually in C# class names are [Pascal Cased](https://www.google.com/amp/s/techterms.com/amp/definition/pascalcase)

Comment: Thank you, i will look into it.

Comment: See my updated answer, much more simple. I got ahead of myself with Events and EventHandlers lol 

Comment: why public static async STRING Filter(string message)?

Comment: Well if you don't need to return the response then that's fine you don't need it, remove `string` use `void` and remove the `return`s. I assumed you want to return the filtered message to the bot class but maybe you dont

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this