# How to declare global variable in Program cs and use it in controllers in .NET 6.0 Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have default Program.cs file from Web Api template in .NET 6.0.
I am adding variable "test" so I can use its value in controllers.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
const string test = "test123";
builder.Configuration.Bind(test);

//rest of the file...
```

And now I want to use variable "test" outside Program.cs but I have no idea how to do it. I cannot just simply use it because when trying to read it in controller like this:

```
string localVar = test;
```

I am getting an error "'test' is not null here. Cannot use local variable or local function declared in a top-level statement in this context".
This is probably some stupid mistake but I can't figure it out...

Comment: is it a variable or a constant? Bind just for binding configuration values. you need to inject a singleton, look into dependency injection

Comment: @MarkHomer it doesn't matter it its const or var - it gives the same error. And thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Voyak `const` is implicitly `static`, so it does matter.

Comment: might want to start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @PeterCsala I want it to be a const (sorry for a mistake, I edited the post). But still error is the same even with const.

Comment: you problem has nothing to do with asp.net, it is simply instance variable referencing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a Variable from another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392017/calling-a-variable-from-another-class)

Comment: @LeiYang unfortunately no because currently file Program.cs (in Web Api .net6 template) looks different than normal class and doesn't have access modifier and I can't use access modifiers for variables/consts inside this file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting C# 9, we don't need to explicitly mention the `Main` method in `Program.cs` file as we can use the top-level statements feature. However, it doesn't mean that we shouldn't use the default Program class in the created file at all. In your case, you have a need to define the static/const property so you can change the newly created structure into the old one.

```
namespace WebApplication;

public class Program
{
    public static string Test { get; private set; }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        Program.Test = "approach1";
        builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(x => x.Test = "approach2");
        ///
}

public class MyOptions
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

I assumed that you have a need to set the value to the `Program.Test` field during runtime, so in the first approach, I used the `static` field with a `private set;` accessor instead of the constant.

In the second approach, I used the C# options feature to configure the `MyOptions.Test` field value, this will be very flexible and useful to write unit tests later. But, you need to inject the `MyOptions` class wherever is required.

In the below controller template, I specified how to access the configured values at `Program.cs` file, inside the `Get` method

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyOptions _myOptions;

    public TestController (IOptions<MyOptions> myOptions)
    {
        _myOptions = myOptions.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        string test1 = Program.Test;
        string test2 = _myOptions.Test;
        ///
    }
```

}

Answer (score 10):

Add `public partial class Program { }` at the very end of your Program.cs file and add constant, property or whatever you like in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Globals.cs` file:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public const string Test = "test123";
}
```

And access it from any class like this:

```
string localVar = Globals.Test;
```

You can also put variables in the class, just make sure you mark them as `public static`.